# Loops in 8051 assembly? (at89s52)

Tags: loops, assembly, insertion-sort, 8051

I am trying to program in **assembly** for an at89s52 microprocessor, I have found a couple of very basic tutorials on youtube that have not helped me much since I am programming in Keil and most are in C, that is why I ask for help here.

I would like to do an insertion sort that accommodates the numbers I have, which are: **05H, 01H, 04H, 02H and 08H**, but as much as I have tried I have not been able to do the cycle with which I would like to do it. I wanted to ask if someone could tell me how I could start, since I can't think of anything to do my insertion sort please, this is my code at the moment:

```
ORG 0000H
    AJMP MAIN
    ORG 0040H
MAIN:   
    MOV DPTR, #70H
    MOV A, #05H
    MOVX @DPTR, A
    
    INC DPTR
    MOV A, #01H
    MOVX @DPTR, A
    
    INC DPTR
    MOV A, #04H
    MOVX @DPTR, A
    
    INC DPTR
    MOV A, #02H
    MOVX @DPTR, A
    
    INC DPTR
    MOV A, #08H
    MOVX @DPTR, A
    
    MOV R0, #1H
    CJNE R0, #5H, CICLO
    
CICLO: //loop
    MOV R1, R0
    
    
END
```

Comment: Write the algorithm first in C or pseudocode or draw a flowchart. Translate into assembly step by step. [Edit] your question if you get stuck, describe what specific issue you have.

Comment: Do you mean "circles" or "cycles" in the title?  (Round shapes on a screen, or clock cycles, or something else cyclic like a data structure?)

Comment: Oh, I think you mean loops, since you're talking about doing an Insertion Sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
MOV DPTR, #70H

L1:

movx a, @dptr

mov r0, a

inc dptr

movx a, @dptr

mov r1, a


clr c

subb a, r0

jc  less

;more

mov a, r1

movx @dptr, a

mov a, dpl

clr c

subb a, #1

jnc L2

dec dph

L2:

mov dpl, a

mov a, r0

movx @dptr, a

jmp L4

less:

mov a, r0

movx @dptr, a

mov a, dpl

clr c

subb a, #1

jnc L3

dec dph

L3:

mov dpl, a

mov a, r1

movx @dptr, a

L4:

inc dptr

mov r0, dpl

mov r1, dph

cjne r0, #70h+5-1, L1       ;Your the Low Address equelly 70h 

cjne r1, #00h, L1       ;Your the High Address equelly 00h

mov dptr, #70h

jmp L1
```

Comment: Please use triple backticks to format your code as `code`.  I did that for you this time, but didn't undo the double-spacing so it still looks like a mess.  Also, even more importantly, answers (especially assembly) should have some text that explain the answer, like how it works, and/or what was wrong with the code in the question.